# How can I increase or decrease the elements under a list with the help of buttons or icons?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
int ticket = 0;

List<Painting> paintingList = [
      Painting(
        title: 'Giacomo Amiconi',
        subTitle: 'Jacob and Rachel',
        artSubtitle: 'National Museum, Warsaw',
        artTitle: '18th Century',
        imageAsset:
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Amigoni_Jacob_and_Rachel.jpg',
      ),
    ];


        return Expanded(
  child: ListView.separated(
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return SizedBox(height: 10);
    },
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: paintingList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      Painting model = paintingList[index];
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
            elevation: 5,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                    child: Icon(Icons.brush, color: orange),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    model.title!,
                    style: artTitle,
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    model.subTitle!,
                    style: artSubtitle,
                  ),
                ),
                Image.network(
                  model.imageAsset!,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    model.artTitle!,
                    style: artTitle,
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    model.artSubtitle!,
                    style: artSubtitle,
                  ),
                  trailing: Text('$ticket'),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                ticket++;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(Icons.add)))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

I created a list named Painting as above and assigned certain values ​​to this list. I didn't add the other 2 Painting() I created to avoid code clutter. I then called the values ​​I created in painting . My goal is to create an add button and increase it each time the user clicks it (like adding a product to the cart). When I do this, yes I can do the augmentation. But the list I create is increasing in all of its elements. I just want to increase or decrease whichever list element I click on the add button next to it.

Comment: you will have to set `paintingList` as  state. i'd suggest looking at `flutter_hooks` to make it easier to manage the state on a widget (`riverpod` for the app state). Also, keep in mind to use key in the returned *item* in the `itemBuider`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `insert` method of list to add an item at the specific index. See the following example

```
paintingList.insert(index, paintingList[i]);
```

Above line will add the same item next to the item that clicked.

Same for removing the item at a specific index you can use `removeAt` method of list.

```
paintingList.removeAt(index);
```